# How to check if a UID is unique using Bash?

Tags: bash, comparison

I'm trying to do a simple bash Script to check if there is a not unique UID in `/etc/passwd`.
I did a script already to display all the UID but I can't figure out how to compare them and return the not unique one if it exists.

Here is the script I wrote:

```
#!/bin/bash
passwd="$(cat /etc/passwd)"
while read -r line; do
    IFS=':' read -ra arrayPasswd <<< "$line"
    echo ${arrayPasswd[2]}
done <<< "$passwd"
```

How could I compare them and return the not unique one in case there is one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a script that outputs all of your UIDs, you can use `sort` and `uniq` programs to get the desired result:

`$ your-script | sort | uniq -d`

`uniq` program takes some lines and deletes consecutive repeats. Flag `-d` makes it output only duplicates and delete unique ones. You need to use `sort` first to make any repetitions consecutive.

Comment: Oh yes why did I forgot about that... 
thank you very much !

Comment: @J.erome oh, is it a requirement of Stack Overflow? I'm pretty new here, so I didn't know about such

Comment: yes it is, you can't mark an answer until your post is 15min old

Answer (score 1):

With awk:

```
$ awk -F: 'a[$3]++==1 { print $3 }' /etc/passwd
```

Explanation:

In an associative array (a.k.a. dictionary), keep a count of occurrences of UIDs.

If any UID is repeated, print it.